# How to pass tag parameter to onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I hava a js function like this...

```
function myfunction(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

and I need to pass parameter from data in a tag. I tried to do:

```
<a id="aTag1" data="some data" onclick="trees(this);" > click me </a>
```

I expect to print in console `"some data"` but instead the console print all the html a tag
Also I tried with `console.log(data['data'])` and `console.log(data.data)` but its undefined
How can I receive the data parameter from the a tag?

Comment: You reference the attribute of the element. You really should be using a data attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you pass `this`, you're passing the whole element object. The thing you want can be achieved by the following snipped:

```
function myfunction(data){
    console.log(data.attributes.data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is usefull. The result is data-test="some data" if I need only the string it would be console.log(data.attributes.data[0]); ??

Comment: This will log "undefined". There has been no property section added to the data prefix,  `data-*`. When using dataset the attribute always starts with `data-` prefix, followed by its defining property; `data-info`, `data-name`, `data-num`, `data-compund-string`, etc... Then when reading you use the property value along with the  dataset.*property* -> camel case `data-compund-string` -> `dataset.compundString`.

Comment: @juandavidentrenese As mentioned, `data.attributes.data[0]` will be undefined. you can use `data.attributes.data.nodeValue` to get `"some data"` value.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the reference of the element, so you need to look at the attributes. Ideally you should use a data attribute.

```js
function myfunction(elem){
    console.log(elem.dataset.test);
}
```

```html
<a id="aTag1" data-test="some data" onclick="myfunction(this);" > click me </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the datset value. You are console logging the entire tag rather than the attributes value. You can also use `el.getAttribute()` as well.

***Important notes:*** In your example you are passing ***data*** into your function. `data` is a reserved word used in both HTML and in JS, I would recommend passing a different parameter into your function. Also your `data-` attribute needs a *property* to go along with the data attribute to make it work as intended. ***Example:*** `data-info`, ***data*** being the prefix and ***info*** is the propert, together `data-info`, it is read using `dataset.info`. [MDN: Using attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [MDN: More on Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

```js
function trees(data){
    console.log(data.dataset.some);
    console.log(data.getAttribute('data-some'))
}
```

```html
<a id="aTag1" data-some="some data" onclick="trees(this);" > click me </a>
```